# Invalid header signature; read 0x7061632C65746144, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CEG0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document]]

Tags: java, scala, csv, apache-poi, xls

I am using `"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "4.1.2"` library to read csv and xls file. since I am able to read .xls file without any problem. But when I try to read .csv file it show me an error that

```
Invalid header signature; read 0x7061632C65746144, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CEG0 - Your file appears
not to be a valid OLE2 document]
```

I found some resources on stack overflow that describes that its file format issue.
But I am sure that my file is .csv file.
I am using play scala for processing file

`val wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file)`
this is how I am reading my file.
any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Apache POI is for reading (mainly) excel files; If you wish to read from CSV, you should use CSVReader (or other csv reader alternatives) instead

Comment: But 2 months before I used it to read the same csv file. But currently its not working. What is behind that?

Comment: I am also downloading csv file online. and uploading it just for testing purpose. but the same error occurs every time.

Comment: "What's behind that [file]?": if you can open and read it with `notepad`, it can't be processed with POI.